# delimite Width in selectCheckboxes tag

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a problem with a  width. The limit is 500px and if the list has a lot of options the result is like this:

http://screencast.com/t/84RaW9kA8vHf

I need to delimit the width to print this and if the width is more than 500px use 2 lines. How can I do it?

```
                        <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!suppliersSelected}" >
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!suppliersName}"/>
                    </apex:selectCheckboxes>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apex:selectCheckboxes is rendered as a table, so you can't just give it a normal attribute to reflow. However, with a bit of CSS, you can do exactly what you're looking for:

```
<style>
    .reflow-table table, .reflow-table table tbody, .reflow-table table tbody tr, .reflow-table table tbody tr td {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .reflow-table {
        max-width: 500px;
    }
</style>
<div class="reflow-table">
    <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!suppliersSelected}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!suppliersName}" />
    </apex:selectCheckboxes>
 </div>
```